# How to setup database through Alembic revision for pytest test cases

Tags: python, database, pytest

I need to alembic migration for executing modified SQL queries instead of `db.create_all()`

Here's what I tried

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def db(test_app):
    flask_migrate.upgrade(revision='ad1185f5b0d0')
    yield


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def create_sample_dataset(db):
    from tests.utils import PrePopulateDBForTest

    PrePopulateDBForTest().create()
    return
```

But `flask_migrate.upgrade()` gets executed but does not commit to the database and will get an error saying `relation "table_name" does not exist`.

Also tried following but did nothing

```
alembic_config = AlembicConfig('migrations/alembic.ini')
alembic_config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', uri)
alembic_upgrade(alembic_config, 'ad1185f5b0d0')
```

Any reason why it is not being committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this for some time and came to the solution below. It uses a database that is deployed with docker compose. The next step would be to also setup and breakdown the docker instance using fixtures. The pytest fixtures perform the following tasks (in chronological order):

1. Create logger
2. Create postgresql database
3. Create sqlalchemy session
4. Create engine from session
5. Create alembic configuration
6. Migrate to the alembic head revision

Code example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def logger() -> Generator:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    yield logger


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def setup_db(logger) -> Generator:
    logger.info("SETUP database")
    uri = conf.settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    if database_exists(uri):
        drop_database(uri)
    create_database(uri)
    yield
    drop_database(uri)
    logger.info("TEARDOWN database")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def db(setup_db, logger) -> Generator:
    logger.info("SETUP session")
    try:
        session = SessionLocal()
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()
    logger.info("TEARDOWN session")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def alembic_engine(db, logger) -> Generator:
    logger.info("SETUP alembic engine")
    yield db.get_bind()
    logger.info("TEARDOWN alembic engine")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def alembic_config(db: Engine, logger):
    logger.info("SETUP alembic config")
    cfg = alembic.config.Config("alembic.ini")
    cfg.set_main_option("script_location", "alembic")
    cfg.set_main_option(
        "sqlalchemy.url", conf.settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
    return cfg


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def alembic_run(alembic_runner, logger):
    logger.info("SETUP alembic migration")
    os.environ["POSTGRES_SERVER"] = "localhost"
    os.environ["POSTGRES_DB"] = "test_db"
    os.environ["POSTGRES_USER"] = "postgres"
    os.environ["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] = "postgres"
    alembic_runner.migrate_up_to("head")
    yield
    alembic_runner.migrate_down_to("base")
    logger.info("TEARDOWN alembic migration")
```